# Unable to remove jdk from my Ubuntu System

Tags: apt, java, jdk, openjdk

I'm tried to remove JDK from my system and I used

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-9*
```

After doing this, I executed `java -version` command on my cmd it reported this message:

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Please could you help me out to remove JDK completely?

Comment: Could you add more details on how you installed the JDK package?

Comment: You have removed java9, but still have java8 !!

Comment: sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
#if not installed the install and remove
#sudo apt-get install openjdk*

#Java manual installation
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update; sudo apt --assume-yes install oracle-java8-installer
#Update default java to installed oracle java (auto update)
sudo update-alternatives --config java

sudo apt --assume-yes install nano
sudo apt update
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle #java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
#export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin:$JBOSS_HOME/bin

Comment: this is how i did

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove OpenJDK-9 and all related file to JDK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785514/how-to-remove-openjdk-9-and-all-related-file-to-jdk)

Answer (score 0):

so far you have removed JDK, try to remove JRE as well.

sudo apt-get remove openjdk-9-jre default-jre default-jre-headless

Try also this command: which java 
it will show you java home directory, you could simply delete it.

Comment: i have tried but still result same

Comment: what does "which java" command show?